# wxPython switching styles in RichTextCtrl does not work

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need some help manipulating styles in text. The example below can be used to demonstrate the issue.
I am using python3 and wxPython 4.1.1.

When you run the script it inserts 3 paragraphs into the text field. Click on one of the red lines and then apply the blue style from the style picker at the bottom. Notice that it sort of adds the style to the already existing style and places it over, but does not change the font size and boldness.
But in the code, each style redefines all the properties of the style including size and weight.

Also notice that if you start a new paragraph yourself with a style selected, switching the styles then does not behave the same way, but works correctly.

Why? What is this? What is happening? :smiley:

I have asked a similar question here, but nobody seems to know the answer and I have not found and solution yet myself.

https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/richtextctrl-changing-style-does-not-replace-previous-style/35066

Thanks.

```
import wx
import wx.richtext as rt


class RichTextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.rtc = rt.RichTextCtrl(self, style=wx.VSCROLL | wx.HSCROLL | wx.NO_BORDER)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # Create style stylesheet and control
        self._stylesheet = rt.RichTextStyleSheet()
        self._stylesheet.SetName('Stylesheet')

        self._style_control = rt.RichTextStyleListBox(self, 1, size=(140, 60))
        self._style_control.SetApplyOnSelection(True)
        self._style_control.SetStyleType(0)
        self._style_control.SetMargins(-5, -5)

        self.rtc.SetStyleSheet(self._stylesheet)
        self._style_control.SetRichTextCtrl(self.rtc)
        self._style_control.SetStyleSheet(self._stylesheet)

        self.sizer.Add(self.rtc, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self._style_control)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self._create_styles()
        self._insert_sample_text()

    def _create_styles(self) -> None:
        """
        Create styles for rich text control.
        :return: None
        """
        # Paragraph style
        stl_paragraph: rt.RichTextAttr = rt.RichTextAttr()
        stl_paragraph.SetFontSize(Numbers.paragraph_font_size)
        stl_paragraph.SetAlignment(wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
        # todo font weight and size is ignored
        stl_paragraph.SetFontWeight(wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL)
        stl_paragraph.SetParagraphSpacingBefore(Numbers.paragraph_spacing)
        stl_paragraph.SetParagraphSpacingAfter(Numbers.paragraph_spacing)
        stl_paragraph.SetBackgroundColour(wx.RED)

        style_paragraph: rt.RichTextParagraphStyleDefinition = rt.RichTextParagraphStyleDefinition(
            Strings.style_paragraph)
        style_paragraph.SetStyle(stl_paragraph)
        style_paragraph.SetNextStyle(Strings.style_paragraph)
        self._stylesheet.AddParagraphStyle(style_paragraph)

        # Paragraph style bold
        stl_paragraph_bold: rt.RichTextAttr = rt.RichTextAttr()
        stl_paragraph_bold.SetFontSize(Numbers.paragraph_font_size_1)
        stl_paragraph_bold.SetAlignment(wx.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT)
        stl_paragraph_bold.SetFontWeight(wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
        stl_paragraph_bold.SetParagraphSpacingBefore(Numbers.paragraph_spacing_bold)
        stl_paragraph_bold.SetParagraphSpacingAfter(Numbers.paragraph_spacing_bold)
        stl_paragraph_bold.SetBackgroundColour(wx.BLUE)

        style_paragraph_bold: rt.RichTextParagraphStyleDefinition = rt.RichTextParagraphStyleDefinition(
            Strings.style_paragraph_bold)
        style_paragraph_bold.SetStyle(stl_paragraph_bold)
        style_paragraph_bold.SetNextStyle(Strings.style_paragraph)
        self._stylesheet.AddParagraphStyle(style_paragraph_bold)

        self.rtc.SetStyleSheet(self._stylesheet)
        self._style_control.SetRichTextCtrl(self.rtc)
        self._style_control.SetStyleSheet(self._stylesheet)
        self._style_control.UpdateStyles()

    def _insert_sample_text(self) -> None:
        """
        Insert sample text.
        :return: None
        """
        self.rtc.BeginParagraphStyle(Strings.style_paragraph)
        self.rtc.WriteText('Example paragraph')
        self.rtc.EndParagraphStyle()
        self.rtc.Newline()

        self.rtc.BeginParagraphStyle(Strings.style_paragraph_bold)
        self.rtc.WriteText('Example paragraph')
        self.rtc.EndParagraphStyle()
        self.rtc.Newline()

        self.rtc.BeginParagraphStyle(Strings.style_paragraph)
        self.rtc.WriteText('Example paragraph')
        self.rtc.EndParagraphStyle()
        self.rtc.Newline()


class Strings:
    """
    Just constants
    """
    style_paragraph: str = 'paragraph'
    style_paragraph_bold: str = 'boldparagraph'


class Numbers:
    paragraph_font_size: int = 10
    paragraph_font_size_1: int = 20
    paragraph_spacing: int = 20
    paragraph_spacing_bold: int = 35


class MyApp(wx.App):
    """
    Main class for running the gui
    """

    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
        self.frame = None

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = RichTextFrame(None, -1, "RichTextCtrl", size=(900, 700), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You don't state your platform, which will help pin the issue down, as on Linux, python 3.6.9 wx 4.1.1 the font size and boldness are applied, as you would expect.

Comment: I am actually on Fedora 32 and Python 3.7.9. Yet when I run the example I wrote and do exactly this:  
  
1. Click the first red line  
  
2. Click on blue "boldparagraph" below in the stylepicker  
I get a normal text with red background and blue line above and below it.  
  
1. Click on the last blank line  
2. Hit Enter key.  
3. Click on "boldparagraph"  
4. Write some text.  
5. Click on red "paragraph" from the style picker below."<br/>
It works correctly